# Will there be any frictional force when the normal force is zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image]

Suppose, I have a solid box with mass $m$. The coefficient of kinetic friction of the plane is $0.2$. There is only one force that is acting on the box, which is $\vec{F}$. Now, even though there is no normal force acting on the box, the box is still touching/in contact with the plane ever so slightly. So, will there be any frictional force experienced by the box?

Comment: Why do you say there is no normal force?

Comment: @Not_Einstein $\vec{F}$ is the resultant force of the weight and another force. So, no normal force exists now.

Comment: If there is gravity there must be normal force, otherwise the block will move down

Comment: Not if there is another force whose vertical component is equal and opposite to the weight.

Comment: Touching = a normal force. Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplified world of physics 101, we would assume there is no friction.

Practically, this is an unusual situation that just doesn't come up much.  If there is no force holding the object to the surface, then any touch is going to accelerate it away from the surface so it doesn't remain.  So the object either never touches, touches and flies away, or touches and there's some force to bring it back.